# ListBox Showing First Item Only

Tags: c#

```
        public Core()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Archive.IntializeObjects();
        Data.Load();
        adultBox.DataSource = display;
    }

    void UpdateUI()
    {
        display.Clear();
        foreach (Lesson l in lessons)
        {
            display.Add(l);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(lessons.Count.ToString());
        adultBox.DisplayMember = "Title";
    }
```

This method updates a separate list to filter from a larger list and then post it to a ListBox. Though the lessons list updates properly and contains multiple objects, only one item is ever shown in the box.

What am I missing?

Comment: We have no idea what platform or technology you are working in. You didnt say and the code doesnt give much away

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
display.Items.Add(l);
```

or

```
display.Items.AddRange(l.ToArray());
```

Comment: Or `display.Items.AddRange(lessons.ToArray());` :). But I've some reserves on the `adultBox.DataSource = display;`. What would that do? What is `display`?  Who knows.

Comment: I think, display is his listbox. HAHAHA. so I assumed.

Comment: Nope. `l` is a single element of the `who knows` collection object. The first snippet is good, the second needs the `[Collection].ToArray()` as value.